# What does my service account need to get around the error "Manage Auditing user right" in robocopy?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, robocopy

I am creating a scheduled task that calls robocopy from a script on Windows Server 2012 R2. It currently throws the following error regardless of it being run manually or from a scheduled task:

```
ERROR : You do not have the Manage Auditing user right.
*****  You need this to copy auditing information (/COPY:U or /COPYALL).
```

The task is set to "Run whether user is logged in or not" and "Run with highest privileges" already. The script is below:

```
Add-Content E:\ITS\CopyScripts\box1-backup-robocopy.log "script running"
#Input the variables for the robocopy script
$Source = "\\box1-prod\images\prod\"
$Destination = "E:\Box1\Backups\images"
$Retries = 1

#This is the Robocopy script
Robocopy.exe $Source $Destination /E /Z /COPYALL /XO /r:$Retries /purge /xd '$RECYCLE.BIN' 'System Volume Information' '._nfs' /log:E:\ITS\CopyScripts\box1-backup-robocopy.log /tee
```

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's in the error message: "Manage Auditing user right".

Comment: @GregAskew I get that... trying to understand what setting is needed to resolve that error. AKA, where to grant that right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run gpedit.msc

Computer > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights >

Manage auditing and security log

Comment: I think this got it but now we have another error that I am hoping you also know: 2015/09/16 13:32:56 ERROR 1307 (0x0000051B) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory E:\Box1\Backups\images\ocr
\JUDICIAL\
This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to work around this and cannot get the auditing rights, you can copy everything EXCEPT the auditing information by replacing /COPYALL with this option:

```
 /COPY:DATSO
```

See also: https://adamtheautomator.com/robocopy/

Comment: All I really needed was to copy with the original creation date in tact, and this worked great. Thanks!